Context keeps resetting when I switch pages in React JS
Im building a React JS with Typescript web application with Context to store the user details. I have implemented the Google SSO and thereafter Im setting the user object in the context. In the first try when I complete the sign in process and navigate to home, the context values are displayed correctly, but when i click on any of the options in the menu bar and navigate to a different page the context resets to the default value.
Below attached is the code base
RouteComponent.tsx
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <CustomeLayout />,
        children: [
            {
                path: `${ROUTES.HOMEPAGEROUTE}`,
                element: <HomePage />,
                errorElement: <NotFoundPage />
            },
            {
                path: `${ROUTES.SERVICESPAGEROUTE}`,
                element: <ServicesPage />
            },
            {
                path: `${ROUTES.ABOUTUSPAGE}`,
                element: <AboutusPage />
            }
        ]
    }
]);

export default function RouteComponent() {
    return (
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    )
}

AuthContext.tsx
export const AuthContextProvider: React.FC<LayoutType> = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<UserType | null>(null);

    //common functionality to set the user details
    const setUserDetails = (data: any) => {
        const currentUser: UserType = {
            firstName: data.displayName.split(" ")[0],
            lastName: data.displayName.split(" ")[1],
            mobileNumber: data.phoneNumber,
            emailAddress: data.email,
            isMFAEnabled: data.phoneNumber ? true : false
        };

        setUser(currentUser)
    };

    //Google SSO login function
    const ssoSignIn = async (): Promise<boolean> => {
        try {
            const response = await ssoSignInFunc();

            if (!response) throw new Error("Unable to complete SSO login");

            setUserDetails(response.user);

            localStorage.setItem('Token', response.user.accessToken);

            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            const err = error as AxiosError;
            throw new Error(err.message);
        }
    };


    const contextValue: AuthContextType = useMemo(() => {
        return {
            ssoSignIn,
            user
        }
    }, [user]);


    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

App.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <RouteComponent />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
}

Once the login is completed the user is navigated to the home page
Login.tsx
const {ssoSignIn} = useContext(AuthContext);
const navigate = useNavigate();

const loginUser = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await ssoSignIn();

      if(!response) setError("Error in Signing in user");

      navigate(ROUTES.HOMEPAGEROUTE);
      
    } catch (error) {
      setError("Error in Signing in user");
    }
  }

I want to keep the user object persisted throughout the application once the value is set.

It is possible that you are using an  tag for navigation, which can cause the page to reload and your state to reset. To prevent this, use the Link component from react-router-dom for client-side navigation.

Im using th Nav.Link component
<Nav.Link href={ROUTES.HOMEPAGEROUTE}>Home</Nav.Link>

If you are confident that a reload does not occur when navigating to another page, try storing the user in localStorage.
const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
    const savedUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    return savedUser ? JSON.parse(savedUser) : null;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
  }, [user]);



Considering the comment you posted I changed from Nav.Link to Link and that worked. Thanks alot.

Nice, for reference, is the Nav.Link component from some library?
